# how enable SSL klokantech tileserver

Tags: docker, ssl, openmaptiles

I'm using this tileserver in my project - https://openmaptiles.com/server/ (i'm using it with Docker).

How to enable HTTPS protocol in webserver (ubuntu server 18.04) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have enabled https via certbot in my server with vhost enabled.

map.conf (http)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName map.xxx.com
ServerAlias map.xxx.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost


ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =map.xxx.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

But the problem is that the /styles/positron/style.json has http request. So there cause Mixed Content problem.

I've tried everything (change http to https in style.json cause other errors), but nothing to do with this problem.

If it can help, maybe you'll found a solution for the next problem.

Edit : Just add

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Host "map.xxx.com"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

on https vhost conf generate by certbot.